# Java Application server experiencing filesystem problems

Tags: filesystems, java, ntfs, windows-server-2003-r2

We have a Java Application server installed on our client's test server. Within application server, a number of threads access the filesystem in a number of ways (using java.io classes). The application server is started as a service. After a number of hours, sometimes up to a day, the filesystem seems to have become unavailable to these threads. On looking at the folders/directories in question on the filesystem, they are still present, appear to have the correct access permissions and do not appear to have exclusive locks on them. Is this possible? Any suggestions as to clues I should look for? Most likely causes?

The Operating system in question is Windows 2003 (Service Pack 2) with 32 bit processor. Filesystem is NTFS JRE is 1.6

I have already posted this on the serverFault Q&A, but it was suggested I pose the question here instead.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your applications closes streams, such as `FileInputStream`, correctly.